# Why does the stock auth Login view require a username field value when I’m using a custom user model?

Tags: django, django-authentication

I’m missing something.

I‘ve got a custom user model in my Django project. It uses e-mail as its username field.

#### myproject/users/models.py:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='E-mail address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
        db_index=True,
    )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'


    objects = CustomUserManager()

    ...
```

#### settings.py:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomUser'
```

I’ve written a view that receives the POST request from my HTML login form, and calls the stock auth login view to get its response:

#### myproject/users/views.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import login

...

def log_in(request, template_name):
    response = login(request, template_name=template_name)

    return response
```

(It will do more than that, but I’ve commented out the other code to eliminate it as a cause of unwanted behaviour I’m seeing.)

When I attempt to log in in the browser (using the e-mail address and password of the superuser created when I did my initial `syncdb`) I get a form error:

```
username: This field is required.
```

How come? I figured that the stock auth login view would use the built-in auth `AuthenticationForm`, which [apparently works with any subclass of `AbstractBaseUser`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-the-built-in-auth-forms).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, got it.

I wrote my login form HTML myself (rather than rendering it using Django’s form template tags), and my e-mail field looked like this:

```
<input id="loginForm_email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Your e-mail adddress">
```

I believe the stock auth login view requires the username-equivalent field to actually be called `username`, like this:

```
<input id="loginForm_email" name="username" type="email" placeholder="Your e-mail adddress">
```

Once I made that change, it worked fine.